# Importing a model in header view class CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently I have a index page where I'm showing the header, the content body and the footer for all my pages which looks like so:

```
<!--include header --->
    <?php $this->load->view('include/header');?>
    <div class="container"><?php $this->load->view($page); ?></div>
    <!--include footer --->
    <?php $this->load->view('include/footer') ;?>
```

Now in my include/header I have a `<li>` tag which takes reference from one of my models to show the count of a particular status for which I'm adding a statement at the top of my header class to get the model:

```
<?php $main['count']=$this->dashboard_model->combined(); 
?>
...
<li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="leads/">Active Leads (<?php echo $count[0]["active"] ?>)</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now this shows the count when I'm in my dashboard page, but when I switch to any other page it gives and error message saying  `Undefined property: CI_Loader::$dashboard_model at line 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the model not loaded in other pages. On your dashboard page the "dashboard_model" model was loaded before you use it in the header. You need to load model before use it on other page.

Comment: Could you show an example of this. I've tried adding this on top of the header View class `$this->load->model('dashboard_model');`  but its still giving the same error

Comment: How to you load model in index page where you hasn't that error?

Comment: In the page where I dont have this error is my dashboard page where I'm loading the model in dashboard controller. Now I have a 50 other controllers so I dont want to import model in each of them, so I want one controller for header that will import the model in all of my pages

Comment: From documentation:
If you find that you need a particular model globally throughout your application, you can tell CodeIgniter to auto-load it during system initialization. This is done by opening the application/config/autoload.php file and adding the model to the autoload array.

Comment: Okay this works but now I'm getting another error. Now it says undefined variable $count in header. But I did add `$main['count']=$this->dashboard_model->combined();` on top of my header class

Comment: Because you define it as $main['count'] and not $count